# Resizing Remote Desktop window without getting scrollbars

Tags: remote-desktop, resolution

I have a Windows 10 computer and a 43 inch 4K monitor.
When I use this computer to connect to a Windows 10 server using Remote Desktop Connection, I want to resize the RDC window to be on 1/4 of my 4K monitor without causing it to use scrollbars.
In other words, I want RDC to behave as if I'm viewing the remote server on a 1080p monitor (equivalent resolution to 1/4 of my 4K screen), rather than causing it to have 4K worth or screen space and have scrollbars.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating the RDP connection, go to the Display tab to set the size of your remote desktop. You can then save this configuration in the .rdp file:

[image]

You can also set a resolution using the `/w:<Width> /h:<Height>` parameters. See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753907(v=ws.11).aspx for more info.

Comment: I use a .rdp file to initiate the connection. These are the first four lines of the file, but the width and height don't end up being 1920x1080: 

`screen mode id:i:2
use multimon:i:0
desktopwidth:i:1920
desktopheight:i:1080`

Comment: What if you initiate the connection from the RDC GUI, as a test? Does setting the slider to `1920 by 1080 pixels` work?

Comment: That seems to work!

Comment: This fails to rescale Remote Windows Desktop when the connectin windows get resized.

Answer (score 2):

Solution

Just add the following line to your .rdp file. You can open the file as an editable text file using the *open with* dialogue.

```
smart sizing:i:1
```

Comment: Where in thar file? How?

Comment: This fails to rescale Remote Windows Desktop when the connectin windows get resized.

Comment: Finaly a fit solution! :) thank you!